# Updating and accessing sqlite from an android service

Tags: android, database, sqlite, service, android-activity

I have a main activity which updates the UI from a DB and each time there is a SMS received from the broadcast receiver, it will call a service to update the DB. The problem is that, is there a tutorial that shows how to handle these sqlite calls and if anyone can point me to the right direction to this.

Answer (score 0):

Calling "updates()" on your DataBase, you can manipulate this with threads right?
(MARAKANA has tutorials to make nice implementations with SQLite)

You have to implement Runnable class. In method "run" you have to put your "update()" method.

regards

Comment: I tried looking, but do you have the link to share, I can't seem to find it :(